# Mint Fungible Token Development Network

Tags: token, substrate-contracts-node

Is it possible to Mint Fungible token on Development (local) Substrate?

https://polkadot.js.org/apps not showing "assets" under "network" tab.

Using substrate-contracts-node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substrate-contracts-node` is a template project for smart contract only, for token test you need to add `Asset` and `Nft` pallet into runtime like [cumulus](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/8d0e4229c580245f8e9a493bc39d0b94a9afa4c9/polkadot-parachains/statemine/src/lib.rs#L573-L574)